# How to specify localized property list?

Tags: ios

I have an ios application which is calling a rest web service. I have created a property list file in my app which contains a dictionary of error codes that will be returned by the server and a corresponding message to show.

I am thinking of having multiple property list files for different languages.

How can i make the app to pick up a specific property list based on locale?

Answer (score 0):

You say that the server is generating an error code and a message.

So I think there are more ways to do it.

First you could send a locale header in your request to the server, so that the server would do all localizations for you (which in my opinion is not as good as solution #2).

So I would prefer the way of letting the server just return error codes and handling the messages on client side. 
You could create a language project in xcode, for each language you want to support: 
http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html#extract

In the localizable.strings file I would do the following:

```
"RestServiceXYErrorTitle_1" = "Authentication failed";
"RestServiceXYErrorMessage_1" = "Your credentials were wrong";
"RestServiceXYErrorTitle_2" = "Resource not available";
"RestServiceXYErrorMessage_2" = "The resource you requested is no longer available";
....
```

Then I would take the error code returned by the server, e.g. 1 and put it together with my localization string:

```
NSString *localizedTitleKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RestServiceXYErrorTitle_%@", errorCode];
NSString *localizedMessageKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RestServiceXYErrorMessage_%@", errorCode];
NSString *errorTitle = NSLocalizedString(localizedTitleKey,@"");
NSString *errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(localizedMessageKey,@"");
```

I think this would be a good solution

Comment: yes i would be implementing solution 2, but there is a possibility that an error code sent from server is not handled here, which will cause problems, thats why i went for property lists....